# find the difference between two table

Tags: php

I have two table where one table shows the overall students and another show the list of student that came to the class. so, I want to compare the two tables to get the list of student that absent the class.

```
<?php  
 function fetch_data()  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "students");  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM worker ORDER BY ID";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {       
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["Course"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["mentor"].'</td>  
                     </tr>  
                          ';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  

 function fetch_data1()  
 {  
      $output1 = '';  
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "students");  
      $sql = "select * from worker1 except select * from worker";  
      $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))  
      {       
      $output1 .= '<tr>  
                          <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["Course"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["mentor"].'</td>  
                     </tr>  
                          ';  
      }  
      return $output1;  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"]))  
 {  
      require_once('tcpdf.php');  
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Generate HTML Table Data To PDF From MySQL Database Using TCPDF In PHP");  
      $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
      $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
      $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
      $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
      $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
      $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
      $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11);  
      $obj_pdf->AddPage();  
      $content = '';  
      $content .= '  
      <h4 align="center">Student Attendance Report</h4><br /> 
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">  
           <tr>  
                <th width="25%">ID</th>  
                <th width="30%">Name</th>  
                <th width="25%">Course</th>  
                <th width="20%">Mentor</th>  
           </tr>  
      ';  
      $content .= fetch_data();  
      $content .= '</table>';  
      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
      $obj_pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Student Attendance Report</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />            
      </head>  
      <body background="pic1.jpg">  
           <br />
           <div class="container">  
                <h4 align="center"> Student Attendance Report</h4><br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                    <div class="col-md-12" align="right">
                    <h4 align="center"><strong>Student Attend</strong></h4>
                     <form method="post">  
                          <input type="submit" name="generate_pdf" class="btn btn-success" value="Generate PDF" />  
                     </form>  
                     </div>
                     <br/>
                     <br/>
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="20%">ID</th>  
                               <th width="30%">Name</th>  
                               <th width="30%">Course</th>  
                               <th width="20%">Mentor</th>  
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     echo fetch_data();  
                     ?>  
                     </table>  


        <br/>
        <h4 align="center"><strong>Student Absence</strong></h4>
        <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="20%">ID</th>  
                     <th width="30%">Name</th>  
                     <th width="30%">Course</th>  
                     <th width="20%">Mentor</th>  
                     </tr>  
                  <?php  
                   echo fetch_data1();  
                   ?>  
        </table>
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
</html>
```

those code are the one that i used to read display the data from the table in webpage. But it only displays the list of student that attend the class and does not display the student that absent from the class.

[worker1 table
list of overall student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg8aO.png)

[worker table
list of student attend the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw9em.png)

Comment: this php coding also enable me to view the page in pdf mode.

Comment: You need another query for that. Also `MySQL does not support the EXCEPT operator`

Comment: okay, so how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

If `worker1` tables contains all the students and `worker` table are those who attended, then you can use `NOT EXISTS` in your query for those who are **absent**.

```
SELECT
ID, Name,Course, mentor
from worker1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT ID, Name,Course, mentor
FROM worker t2
WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
)
```

Haven't tested the query above, but the idea is the same.